# How to fix VALUE / ASSERTION error? I'm trying to scrape a table that has six columns, but three are merged

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, pandas-datareader

I tried to scrape a table that has merged columns. However, I got the following error that says **"ValueError: 2 columns passed, passed data had 6 columns."** I'm attaching the picture of the table for your reference. You can see my current code right below.

```
 df = pd.DataFrame(data=all_rows,columns=headings) 
 df.head()
```

[image: THE ERROR - PICTURE]

T.I.A,

Comment: Not enough information here

Comment: How do I split merged columns?

Comment: What is the original table structure? What is "merged columns"? What is on the picture, where are the columns `['headings', 'temp']`? Your question is incomprehensible. Try to look at it as someone who doesn't know what you are working at.

Comment: Yeah, man. I'm sorry - I posted the wrong code before. The original table structure is in the picture. Or you can check it here, https://www.rupeevest.com/Mutual-Fund-Holdings/100325. All I'm trying to do is scrape the table in its original structure. Thanks,

Comment: Still incomprehensible. What is original table, where is it? In CSV file? What do you want to do with it? Scrape? What is scrape? Usually people post the text representation of their data/code, then what they want to get, and then what they got. It seems you have a problem with it.